# set multiple validation on textField in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitextfield

I am working on a app in iOS in which i uses multiple textfield on page and I have to set different validation for textField.Suppose for one textfield I want to allow input only charaters and for one I want to input only numbers. How would i do this . Any Suggestion!
I used the below code but its working on only first textfield.

```
 - (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range      replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
if (!string.length) 
    return YES;

if (textField == self.tmpTextField)
{
    NSString *newString = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];
    NSString *expression = @"^([0-9]+)?(\\.([0-9]{1,2})?)?$";
    NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpressionregularExpressionWithPattern:expression 
                                                                           options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive 
                                                                             error:nil];
    NSUInteger numberOfMatches = [regex numberOfMatchesInString:newString
                                                        options:0
                                                          range:NSMakeRange(0, [newString length])];        
    if (numberOfMatches == 0)
        return NO;        
}
return YES;
}
```

Comment: What is the name of the second textfield.

Comment: How about using `keyboardType` to restrict text entry in the textFields?

Comment: Hey Utkarsh keyboardType is just to open a specific keyboard as decimal pad ,number pad and characters keyboard when textfield is edited.To stop typing characters in a text field you need to restrict it. I have given a code in answers how i stop a textField to stop entering characters once you check.....Thanks

Comment: n00bProgrammer, keyboardType can has differents between iPhone and iPad platforms and user can paste the text into textField also.

Answer (score 2):

```
#define ACCEPTABLE_CHARACTERS @"0123456789"
```

-(BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{

```
if ([textField isEqual:zipCode]) {

    NSCharacterSet *cs = [[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:ACCEPTABLE_CHARACTERS] invertedSet];
    NSString *filtered = [[string componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:cs] componentsJoinedByString:@""];
    return [string isEqualToString:filtered];


}

return YES;
```

}

Answer (score 1):

used TAG property of your text  field and then after differentiate it like below.

```
ex. set property like this.

    textfielfname.tag =0;
    textfielfemail.tag =1;

    if(textField.tag == 0)
    {
       NSLog(@"First text field");
    }
     else{
           NSLog(@"Second text field");
         }
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the textFiel to only text is: self.tmpTextField, if not change it in this code:

```
 -(BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
NSString *expression = @"^([0-9]+)?(\\.([0-9]{1,2})?)?$";
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:expression
                                                                      options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive
                                                                        error:nil];
NSUInteger numberOfMatches = [regex numberOfMatchesInString:string
                                                    options:0
                                                      range:NSMakeRange(0, [string length])];

if (numberOfMatches == 0)
{
    if (textField == self.tmpTextField)
    {
        return YES;
    } else {
        return NO;
    }
}
else
{

    if (textField == self.tmpTextField)
    {
        return NO;
    }
    else
    {
        return YES;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Hello Onik, Thanks for suggestion. But this code did not allow me to type any thing in first text field and in second text field , allow me to type characters and numbers both. My Problem still stands there!

Comment: Hello Onik, You can assume that my first text field is for Name which only contain characters and second text field is number which only contain numbers between 0-9 nothing else

Comment: @sumitkapoor Hi, I update my code and test it (yesterday I didn't have computer). Works fine if your textField to text is:  self.tmpTextField.

Comment: Don't forget put both delegates.

Comment: Hey Onik I solved my problem last night and its really simple solution for me and thanks for your code.I answered this question and code of it once you check......

Answer (score 0):

All the delegate methods for UITextField (and UITextView, for that matter) include a pointer to the text field in question.

You can either set up separate objects to be the delegate of each text field, or write delegate methods that run different code based on which text field is passed in to the delegate method. I find setting up separate objects to serve as delegates of each text field is usually more trouble than it's worth.

To write delegate methods that handle all your text fields, just set up outlets to each text field. You can then use a switch statement or an if statement to branch based on the field. (A switch statement works because an object pointer in Objective C is a pointer, which is a type of scalar. You might have to cast it to an unsigned long to avoid a complaint from the compiler though.

In your header:

```
IBOutlet UITextField *textField1;
IBOutlet UITextField *textField2;
IBOutlet UITextField *textField3;
```

You can Set tags in Storyboard 0,1 and 2 respectively.

If you want to set it programatically then

```
textField1.tag = 0;
textField2.tag = 1;
textField3.tag = 2;
```

In your .m file:

```
- (BOOL)textField: (UITextField *) textField 
    shouldChangeCharactersInRange: (NSRange) range      
    replacementString: (NSString *) string
{
  switch (textField.tag)
  {
    case 0:
      //Code for textField1
      break;
    case 1:
      //Code for textField2
      break;
    case 2:
      //Code for textField3
      break;
  }
}
```